# Auto scaling components with Java JFrame

Tags: java, resize, jframe, setbounds

I'm coding on Java with visualswing4eclipse. My environmentis Eclipse IDE Version: Luna Service Release 2 (4.4.2). I'm trying to write a function, which auto resize all components inside frame when user change size of window. Here's code:

```
private void componentComponentResized(ComponentEvent event) {

    int a=getContentPane().getWidth();
    int b=getContentPane().getHeight();
    Font font1 = new Font(Font.SANS_SERIF, 2, (int) (b*0.05));

    jTextField0.setBounds((int) (a*0.3), (int) (b*0.1), (int) (0.68*a), (int) (0.1*b));
    jLabel0.setBounds((int) (a*0.02), (int) (b*0.1), (int) (a*0.27), (int) (0.1*b));   
//  jLabel0.setFont(font1);
//  jTextField0.setFont(font1);
}
```

for now, setBounds work properly, but if I uncomment setFont, setBounds stop working, it's like I wasn't write lines with setBound. How can I solve this problem?

edit: I created new GroupLayout to set position of components in this way:

```
 private void initComponents() {
 setLayout(new GroupLayout());
```

Could I use this layout in auto resize function? If not, which layout is good choice for me?
[Here's frame's view in basic size](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nO3H1.png)

Comment: use a layout manager

Comment: Im using one of layout manager: GroupLayout. Isn't it good to scaling components?